# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with Amazonaws S3

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-s3, localhost

I have a django application and using javascript to directly upload files to an s3 bucket after signing the upload in django backend all of this happening on my localhost.
The problem is i am getting an error bellow:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

the client side javascript to upload the file after signing it

```
function uploadFile(file, s3Data, url){
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("POST", s3Data.url);

          var postData = new FormData();
          for(key in s3Data.fields){
              console.log(key, s3Data.fields[key]) // the out put of this is bellow
            postData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
          }
          postData.append('file', file);

          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
              if(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204){
                alert("File uploaded.");
              }
              else{
                alert("Could not upload file.");
              }
           }
      };
      xhr.send(postData);
    }
```

the output of console.log(key, s3Data.fields[key]) above is

```
policy KJDLSKAFJLASKDFJLSAKDJFLKASJDFLKSAJDFLSKADJFLKSAJDFLKJSAD
Content-Type image/jpeg
acl public-read
signature lkjadflkjda
key add.jpg
AWSAccessKeyId LKAJDLKFJADFADD
```

note: i modified the output result content not to put it public.

and the file object is:

```
File {name: "add.jpg", lastModified: 1472705615906, lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 01 2016 12:53:35 GMT+0800 (MYT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 93156…}
```

the django sign_s3 function if its need is:

```
def sign_s3(request):
    S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    file_name = request.GET.get('file_name')
    file_type = request.GET.get('file_type')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
        Key = file_name,
        Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
        Conditions = [
            {"acl": "public-read"},
            {"Content_Type": file_type},
        ],
        ExpiresIn = 3600
    )
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
        'data': presigned_post,
        'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
    }))
```

EDIT: I have played around with policy in bucket permission and now i got a different error:

my policy is:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                ],
                "Principal": "*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

and the error i am getting:

```
POST https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ 403 (Forbidden)
uploadFile @     
xhr.onreadystatechange @ 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content_Type", "image/jpeg"]</Message><RequestId>11EB24540D294B6F</RequestId><HostId>klasjdfl;skajdflksdjfl;ksdjf;lskdjfl;sakjdfl;skadjfl;skadjflsdkjfl;kdsajflksadjfl;ksajdf;lkadsjf</HostId></Error>
```

EDIT 2: removing content type from sign_s3 function enables me to upload files. And i don't understand why !

EDIT 3: Solved ! i had a typo in the sign_s3 funtion as the content_type in Condition should have been content-type